# Flexbox shrinking main container when main container is horizontal flex box

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to create a simple layout for my SPA where I have a header component, which should be shown all the time. A footer component, which should be either at the bottom of the screen or if the main content component is bigger than the screen, it should be below the content component. And a main content component which should get the rest of the space if the screen is bigger than the content, so the footer component gets rendered at the bottom.

Currently I've reproduced my layout in this [codepen](https://codepen.io/JanPeter/pen/LjaRyN?editors=1100). But if you shrink the result window of the codepen enough, you'll get to a point where I can't see the Test2 text because the footer component is on top of it. The behaviour I would expect is, that I can see the Test2 text and I'm able to scroll down to the footer component.

It works if the content component is not a flex box with `flex-direction: row`. Any ideas why this doesn't work?

In my SPA I'm using React, so I don't want to use any JavaScript for this.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.main {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 30px;
}

.test {
  display: block;
}

.footer {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      Main
      <div class="test">Test1<br />Test2<br/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add flex: 1 0 auto to .main class. Flex properties are flex-grow, flex-shrink, and the flex-basis. So with 0 it is told to not shrink.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.main {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  min-height: 30px;
}

.test {
  display: block;
}

.footer {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="main">
      Main
      <div class="test">Test1<br />Test2<br/></div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. I needed to add a div with `display: block;` around my content and I added `justify-content: space-between;` to my container component. Little hacky but it works...

That's my final code:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.page {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.block {
  display: block;
}

.main {
  background: red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.test {
  display: block;
}

.footer {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="header">Header</div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="block">
    <div class="main">
      Main
      <div class="test">Test1<br />Test2<br/></div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">Footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```